# Using cURL to update inventory in BigCommerce

Tags: php, curl, bigcommerce, inventory-management

I am using the following code to update products in bigcommerce with new inventory numbers from our Amazon listings - it works perfectly for any product that does not have an option set (specifically gloves and shirts, which obviously have separate inventory levels for each S, M, L).

```
    $api_url = 'https://store-558hrkjw.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/'.$nearrow['ProductID'].'.json';//put inventory
    $StockdataRAW = array('inventory_level' => 500);//$nearrow['CurrentStockLevel']
    $Stockdata = json_encode($StockdataRAW);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Content-type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json') );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $Stockdata);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "UID:PW" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    // Switch on verbose information and display it on the web page.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('php://output', 'w+'));
    $response = curl_exec( $ch );
    $result = json_decode($response);
    print_r($result);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

When i use this code for the options i get a 404 for each product id - any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working for products without option sets because you're hitting the [products endpoint](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products#update-a-product), which is used for single products, without option sets/variations.

If you have products with options/variations (such as gloves and shirts), those are going to be SKUs, and you can update those using the [SKUs endpoint](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products/skus#update-a-product-sku) -- make sure you have the proper id associated with each SKU.

[Here are the API docs](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/products), which you can reference if you run into any more problems. Note the difference between the `Product` and `SKU` objects.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but it looks like you're not telling the api which option you are referring to, so it can't reply correctly and gives you a 404 as a result.